# How to select a matched autocompletion item

Tags: autocompletion

I want to select the 6th item (here `readImage`) in the auto-completion items.

[image]

The normal way i knew is pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> for 6 times until the matched word is selected and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

I tried different solutions:

1. With the mouse:

   ```
   :set mouse=a
   ```

   then moving my cursor on the 6th word,and clicking mouse,no effect.
2. By entering a number:

   Pressing <kbd>6</kbd>, no effect.

What is your smart way to select matched item in auto-completion?

My vim version on mouse is the following:

```
vim --version | tr -s  " " "\n" |grep mouse
+mouse_sgr
-mouse_sysmouse
+mouse_urxvt
+mouse_xterm
+mouse
-mouseshape
+mouse_dec
-mouse_gpm
-mouse_jsbterm
+mouse_netterm
```

Comment: Skimming ':h compl-generic' suggests this is a feature request.

Comment: @RobMosher do you mean this question is a feature request or the ability to select items using a number has been requested already?

Answer (score 4):

You can select the currently highlighted `:h ins-completion` by pressing `Ctrl-y` and discard the completions and go back to original text by pressing `Ctrl-E`. For more information, see `:h complete_CTRL-E` and `:h complete_CTRL-Y`

- **Ctrl-E**
  When completion is active you can use CTRL-E to stop it and go back to the originally typed text. The CTRL-E will not be inserted.
- **Ctrl-Y**
  When the popup menu is displayed you can use CTRL-Y to stop completion and
  accept the currently selected entry.  The CTRL-Y is not inserted.  Typing a
  space, Enter, or some other unprintable character will leave completion mode
  and insert that typed character.

For some more completion-menu keys, you can read `:h popupmenu-keys`

Comment: Looks like OP wants to be able to select non-current item with a mouse or some shortcut avoiding C-n/C-p

Answer (score 1):

`patch 8.1.1068` introduced a new function [:h complete_info](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#complete_info%28%29):

```
    patch 8.1.1068: cannot get all the information about current completion

    Problem:    Cannot get all the information about current completion.
    Solution:   Add complete_info(). (Shougo, Hirohito Higashi, closes #4106)
```

You can create map like this:

```
" map 1-9 to nth item
" map shift+{1-9} to last nth item
let s:shiftKeys = '!@#$%^&*('
for s:i in range(1, 9)
  exe printf('inoremap <expr> %d pumvisible() ? <sid>select_pum(%d - 1) : %d ', s:i, s:i, s:i)
  let skey = s:shiftKeys[s:i-1]
  exe printf('inoremap <expr> %s pumvisible() ? <sid>select_pum(-%d) : "%s" ', skey, s:i, skey)
endfor

" map 0 to original item
inoremap <expr> 0 pumvisible() ? '<c-e>' : 0

function! s:select_pum(index)
  let compInfo = complete_info()
  let idx = a:index >= 0 ? a:index : a:index + len(compInfo.items)
  let d = idx - compInfo.selected
  return repeat( d > 0 ? "\<c-n>" : "\<c-p>", abs(d))
endfunction
```